# SharePoint 2013 view with date filter

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, list-view, view

I'm using SharePoint 2013 and I want to create a view to find items created between two dates. But I dont know how to pass two dates to View.aspx and apply filter.

Answer (score 1):

Click on modify view on that specific page, there is filter section where you can set the filter conditions. for example created date > date1 and created date < date2.[image: see below]

Comment: Actually I know this but how to pass two dates to view via URL?

Comment: If you are trying to do this via code, you can try using REST API  that has filter option where you can pass the date values.

Answer (score 1):

Filter View by Date

You can only use **[Today]** in the View Filter options
(add or substract the number of days, 5475 = 15 years)

Important: Do NOT use spaces in these Formulas!!!

[image]

For more advanced use of [Today] Filtering (Filter by current Month etc.) see: http://blog.pentalogic.net/2009/11/howto-filter-items-current-calendar-month-view-sharepoint/